# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when calling TextView getLineEnd

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have the TextView maxLine set to 5 and when I call getLineEnd(4) on a view that most definitely has 5+ lines it gives me the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I can't figure out why this is happening. please help? Thanks!

**logs**

```
06-12 02:50:42.256 30175 30175 E ErrorPageActivity: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=27; index=30
06-12 02:50:42.256 30175 30175 E ErrorPageActivity:     at android.text.StaticLayout.getLineStart(StaticLayout.java:1151)
06-12 02:50:42.256 30175 30175 E ErrorPageActivity:     at android.text.Layout.getLineEnd(Layout.java:1409)
06-12 02:50:42.256 30175 30175 E ErrorPageActivity:     at com.imdb.livingroom.firetv.util.TextViewExtensionsKt.visibleText(TextViewExtensions.kt:13)
```

**TextViewExtensions**

```
fun TextView.visibleText(): String {
    val end = layout.getLineEnd(4)
    return layout.text.toString().substring(0,end);
}
```

**layout xml**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_review_description"
        style="@style/text_body_two"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/review_description_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/micro_margin"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/medium_margin"
        android:importantForAutofill= "noExcludeDescendants"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_nickname"
        />
```

Here’s a picture of the view. The detailed review block is the textview in question

[image]

Answer (score 0):

fixed by changing it to `val end = layout.getLineEnd(layout.lineCount - 1)`